Is this identity for the golden ratio published anywhere?
I recently found a rather attractive identity that allows one to find any power $n$ of the golden ratio $\varphi$ as a function of another power $k$ of $\varphi$ and the $n^{th}$ and $n-1^{th}$ Fibonacci numbers.
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{F_k}\varphi^k-\frac{F_{k-1}F_n-F_kF_{n-1}}{F_k}$
I have searched all over but have not found any prior reference to this identity. Does anyone know if this identity has been published anywhere?
If a derivation is helpful, here is one way to do it…
Binet’s equation allows one to find any power $n$ of $\varphi$ as a function of $\varphi$ and the $n^{th}$ and $n-1^{th}$ Fibonacci numbers.
$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}$
From this, we can recover the defining polynomial for which $\varphi$ is the positive root.
$\varphi^2=\varphi+1$
Solving for $\varphi$ and substituting back into Binet’s equation gives
$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi^2-F_n+F_{n-1}$
allowing one to find any power $n$ of $\varphi$ as a function of $\varphi^2$ and the $n^{th}$ and $n-1^{th}$ Fibonacci numbers.
Now, from this quadratic equation we have
$\varphi^3=2\varphi^2-1$
Solving for $\varphi^2$ and substituting back into the quadratic equation gives
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{2}\varphi^3-\frac{F_n}{2}+F_{n-1}$
allowing one to find any power $n$ of $\varphi$ as a function of $\varphi^3$ and the $n^{th}$ and $n-1^{th}$ Fibonacci numbers.
Repeating this process results in a sequence of equations having as its first five entries
$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}$
$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi^2-F_n+F_{n-1}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{2}\varphi^3-\frac{F_n}{2}+F_{n-1}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{3}\varphi^4-\frac{2}{3}F_n+F_{n-1}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{5}\varphi^5-\frac{3}{5}F_n+F_{n-1}$
Although the pattern is beginning to be apparent, rearranging and including ‘ghosted’ terms reveals the pattern more clearly.
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{1}\varphi^1-\frac{0F_n-1F_{n-1}}{1}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{1}\varphi^2-\frac{1F_n-1F_{n-1}}{1}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{2}\varphi^3-\frac{1F_n-2F_{n-1}}{2}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{3}\varphi^4-\frac{2F_n-3F_{n-1}}{3}$
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{5}\varphi^5-\frac{3F_n-5F_{n-1}}{5}$
It is clear that if $n=k$, the terms cancel leaving $\varphi^n=\varphi^k$.
The identity works if $k>n$ and if the Fibonacci numbers are extended to negative indices, e.g. $F_{0}=0$, $F_{-1}=1$, $F_{-2}=-1$, $F_{-3}=2$, $F_{-4}=-3$, etc.

Thank you. I wouldn't have thought to approach it that way.

I can't say that I have found any prior reference to the identity. Then again, I haven't found any prior reference to the equation $84367\times49253=4155327851$, so there's that.

It is known that
$$
 \varphi^n = F_n \varphi + F_{n-1} \, ,
$$
see for example decomposition of powers in Fibonacci sequence. Using this for two indices $n$ and $k$
$$
 \varphi^n = F_n \varphi + F_{n-1} \\
 \varphi^k = F_k \varphi + F_{k-1} 
$$
implies
$$
 \varphi^n F_k - \varphi^k F_n = F_{n-1} F_k - F_{k-1} F_n \, ,
$$
and that is equivalent to your identity
$$
 \varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{F_k}\varphi^k-\frac{F_{k-1}F_n-F_kF_{n-1}}{F_k} \, .
$$

Yes, Martin. I saw that immediately with your first comment. That is certainly a much simpler and more elegant derivation. I would have expected something like this to come up in my search, but the furthest every source got was Binet's equation. If your point is that it is obvious, I could say the same about Binet's equation. I fell upon that before I knew it had a name as well. What I thought was odd was that the more general case was nowhere to be found. If it has been published, I'd like to be able to give proper credit.

Update - Not an answer, but I came across an identity called d'Ocagne's identity:
$F_{n}F_{k+1}-F_{n+1}F_{k}=(-1)^kF_{n-k}$
With a little manipulation, the identity in question can also be expressed as:
$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n}{F_k}\varphi^k+(-1)^{k+1}\frac{F_{n-k}}{F_k}$

Proof of identity appears here
